# Tempered Glass in Window adjacent to Patio Door

Tags: windows

Is tempered glass required in a window within 24 inches of a fixed glass panel of a two panel sliding patio door?

Comment: As far as I remember tempered glass is required on all doors and within 24”.

Comment: Main rule I'm aware of (does not mean there are not others I'm not aware of) has to do will sill height above the floor.

Answer (score 1):

As Ecnerwal noted, IRC code of 2018 required "glass within 24" of ANY doorway to have tempered glass if the glass within the 24" distance was LESS THAN 60" off the floor level".